# Jenkins Python API, create_node(), error: 400

Tags: python, jenkins, bad-request

I'm setting my jenkins environment and, as part of this process, I need to create a slave node.

Bellow follow the script that is crashing:

> `import jenkins
>   server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:9090')
>   server.create_node('slave')`

Follows the output:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 1156, in create_node
    self._build_url(CREATE_NODE, params), b''))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jenkins/__init__.py", line 341, in jenkins_open
    response = urlopen(req, timeout=self.timeout).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`

Comment: Check you machine network proxy settings. Sometimes that will cause user request errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use jenkinsapi module,

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
server = Jenkins('http://localhost:9090')
server.create_node('slave')
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in python-jenkins 0.4.11, which was fixed by commit 
[302eb5dad6439842e076fead5bd76f20f615e6a8](https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/python-jenkins/commit/?id=302eb5dad6439842e076fead5bd76f20f615e6a8).

I got a similar error, upgrading python-jenkins fixed it.